# HTML semantics and styling

Tags: html, css

My question is this – is it still best practice to use certain HTML tags even if you would then need to style them differently to how a browser interprets and displays those tags?

For example – the HTML5 `<blockquote>` tag will start on its own line, with default margin and padding, and with an indent.

However – if you do not wish there to be an indent, should you still use the `<blockquote>` tags in order to convey meaning to the browser and search engine, and then apply CSS to reduce/rid the indent, or should you just use a `<p>` tag for example?

It’s not much effort to restyle the blockquote element, and I assume that it is important to use the tags that most accurately convey the meaning of their contents, but at the same time I do not want to get into a habit of writing extra code if it is considered best practice not to do so.

Comment: Treat your page as a document first; the styling is just a layer on top.

Comment: Worth mentioning that a lot of the default styling will be removed anyway if you're using CSS resets. The only reason why someone might use an element based on default styling alone is just laziness, except it might add even more work due to differences in default styling between browsers.

Comment: "Do what your heart says, Son!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I assume that it is important to use the tags that most accurately
>   convey the meaning of their contents

You assume correctly.

I would say **yes**, absolutely always try to use the appropriate element for the type of content/purpose you intend. Elements have names/designations for a reason, so your code can be structured in a way that makes semantic sense. Why is this important? Well ignoring SEO for which it plays an important part, or ease of access regarding your code, **this is the intended design of HTML**.

Not using a specific element because it has default styling applied is not a sensible or really logical course of action in this context. This is especially in light of the fact that when you compare [**browser-specific styling**](https://github.com/sw4/revert.css), *most* elements may have default styles applied.

> I do not want to get into a habit of writing extra code if it is
>   considered best practice not to do so

Bad practice to some degree is subjective, otherwise it is simply right or wrong- in this case it wont be game breaking to not use the correct tags, however you will be going against their intended use according to specification, so **it would most certainly be bad practice.**

See:

1. [Semantic HTML (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML)
2. [Semantic Web (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the tags which are most aligned with the semantics of your content. Don't concern yourself with styling when constructing your HTML doc, as you could have different styles for different resolutions (smartphone, tablet, desktop) or even different mediums (web browser, screen reader, braille display, whatever device come out in the future...)

The following talks about class names specifically, but it does drive home the importance of semantic correctness:

ref: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 gives us many new elements to describe parts of a Web page, such as `header`, `footer`, `nav`, `section`, `article`, `aside` and so on. These exist because we Web developers actually wanted such semantics. How did the authors of the HTML5 specification know this? Because in 2005 [Google analyzed 1 billion pages](http://code.google.com/webstats/) to see what authors were using as class names on divs and other elements. More recently, in 2008, [Opera MAMA](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/mama-markup-report-part-2/) analyzed 3 million URLs to see the [top class names](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/572/classlist-url.htm) and [top IDs](http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/572/idlist-url.htm) used in the wild. These analyses revealed that authors wanted to mark up these areas of the page but had no elements to do so, other than the humble and generic div, to which they then added descriptive classes and IDs.
(HTML5 Doctor has many articles about [HTML5 semantics](http://html5doctor.com/article-archive/).)

[Read](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/18/html5-semantics-2/)

Answer (score 1):

You use the blockquote tag to denote that the content is a quote. 
The default style provided by the mark-up communicates information to the one interpreting or decoding the sign.

http://html5doctor.com/blockquote-q-cite/

It is not only a matter of the default style of the mark-up element. 
By using CSS you can create a variation of that basic style. And this is certainly valid for the blockquote. The default style does not provide quotes just padding and margin. It is provided by the CSS quotes property. And this is just one way of styling a quote. You can have a left border on the quote, italic, ...

```
blockquote {
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/simple-and-nice-blockquote-styling/

Answer (score 0):

This is largely opinion-based, and opinions on matters like this are often expressed almost as religious convictions, with little or no factual evidence or arguments presented. However, I will try to deal with the issue on a technical basis, focusing on the example given. (It’s a good example and does not take us too easily too deep into semantic jungles.)

The `blockquote` element is defined as structural rather than semantic. It does not say anything about the *meaning* of its content (it might be about apples, God, or screwdrivers), only about its structural relation with the enclosing document: the content is a copy of some content taken from an external source, i.e. from outside the document – that is, a quotation – and it is a “block quotation” as opposite to “inline quotation”, which means little (if anything) else than its default rendering being a block.

In practice, `blockquote` has widely been just simply to indent text, especially in the old days, before CSS was generally available. This is one reason why there is no sign of search engines (or browsers) making any use of the structural relationship (or “semantics”, if you want to put it that way) nominally expressed by the element. There are many things that search engines *could* do with such information. They just don’t. It is questionable if they ever will: too much content would be incorrectly treated as quoted, and there is too much content that is actually quoted but not marked with `blockquote`.

Thus, the effect of `blockquote` is in practice just the default rendering, with certain margins on all sides. When CSS is disabled or overridden for some reason, this is *the* rendering, and you should try to use HTML markup that gives you *tolerable* rendering even without CSS. This can be seen as the good reason for using `blockquote` for block quotations. On the other hand, if your block quotations have been clearly indicated as quotations in other methods, such as introductory phrases or headings, this argument does not really apply.

On the other hand, there is no good reason *not* to use `blockquote` just because you don’t want the indent. In that case, you must have some other method of visually distinguishing the block quotation from other content, such as using a background color, a different font, or maybe large decorative quotation marks. You would naturally be using CSS for that, and compared to what you do with it, setting `margin-left: 0` is a trivial thing to do.

Moreover, even though browsers and general search engines ignore the structural meaning of `blockquote`, you (or your organization) may decide to do otherwise. You can choose to mark block quotations uniformly in order to be able to find them easily (for statistical, checking, or other purposes). You could achieve the same by using, say, `class=quote` consistently, but why not use an element when you can?